# Using Tiny mce with Vue.js, Looking for Documentation For Installing Link Plugin

Tags: vue.js, tinymce

I am using Tiny mce with Vue.js and Laravel. I have the basic Tiny editor working. I found this [Link Pluin]: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/plugins/link/.

I cannot seem to find instructions on how to install the plugin.

Install by running

```
npm install @tinymce/tinymce-vue
```

imported into the vue component with this line

`import Editor from "@tinymce/tinymce-vue";`

in the component I have:

```
 <editor
      api-key="mykey"
      cloud-channel="5"
      :disabled="false"
      id="uuid"
      :init="{  }"
      initial-value
      model-events
      plugins
      tag-name="div"
      toolbar
      value
      v-model="post.body"
    ></editor>
```

Thank you

---

Update:
I changed the plugin line to this:

```
 :init="{plugins: 'link', menubar: 'insert', toolbar: 'link', default_link_target: '_blank'}"
```

Now there is a link button in the menu and the link feature works. There are no other menu options, only a link button now. The link text is white and cannot be seen. Any suggestions would help. Thank you.

---

Update:
I solved this issue. I also added two more plugins: `wordcount` and `image`

Here is the final init:

```
 :init="{plugins: 'link, wordcount, image', default_link_target: '_blank'}"
```

This works also:

```
 :init="{plugins: 'link wordcount image', default_link_target: '_blank'}"
```

Note: The list of plugins should be enclosed in single quotes and separated by a comma or space.

I wrote a short blog [post]:https://david.dukesnuz.com/blog/6/how-to-add-the-link-word-count-and-image-plugins-to-tinymce-editor-when-using-vuejs on this topic.

Comment: How are you integrating TinyMCE with Vue?  Are you using a wrapper/component like this?  https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-vue  Without knowing how you are integrating things it will be hard to provide concrete guidance.

Comment: @MichaelFromin  just added the code thank you